# Trying to place an applet as a component using embedded in vaadin 7

Tags: java, jar, applet, vaadin

Trying to integrate a java applet in my website created using vaadin 7. I am trying to do it using embedded and adding it to the layout. This is what I have right now.

```
public class DeviceConfigure extends CustomComponent implements View {


@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;
@AutoGenerated


public DeviceConfigure() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

    Resource res = new ThemeResource("img/stars.jar");
    Embedded jarFile = new Embedded("Jar File", res);
    mainLayout.addComponent(jarFile);

}
private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {
    // common part: create layout
    mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
    mainLayout.setImmediate(false);
    mainLayout.setWidth("860px");
    mainLayout.setHeight("510px");

    // top-level component properties
    setWidth("860px");
    setHeight("510px");

    return mainLayout;
}
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

I've tried different things like setting the minetype, archive etc.. but can't get it to work. Whenever I navigate to the page the section where the applet should be is just blank. Is there something that I am missing that I'm just not seeing. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read and reply to this.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've tried that and tested it after playing with the setting numerous times still no luck. Thank you though for the response.

Comment: *"no luck."*  What is that supposed to mean?  You could not figure how to produce the console?  You see the console but it has no output even at highest level?  You want me to play '20 questions' with you?  Note in regards to the last question, I don't play that game.  Either increase the quality of your replies or you can rely on the help of someone else.

Comment: Are you sure that the Embedded object does create the code required to embed and applet on the web page? In vaadin 6 you have to use a addon for this (https://vaadin.com/de/directory#addon/appletintegration) and I think the same is true for vaadin 7